# How to filter pandas dataframe which contains a mixture of string and float?

Tags: pandas

**Data**

```
 {'G1': {0: '1927 (57.83%)',
  1: '45.00 [39.00 - 51.00]',
  2: '909 (27.28%)',
  3: '2029 (60.89%)',
  4: '393 (11.79%)',
  5: '1 (0.03%)',
  6: '577 (17.32%)',
  7: '0 (0.00%)',
  8: '0 (0.00%)',
  9: '2257 (67.74%)',
  10: '0 (0.00%)',
  11: '0 (0.00%)',
  12: '0 (0.00%)',
  13: np.nan,
  14: '0 (0.00%)',
  15: '1019 (30.58%)',
  16: '802 (24.07%)',
  17: '1091 (32.74%)',
  18: '420 (12.61%)',
  19: np.nan,
  20: '0 (0.00%)',
  21: '1433 (43.01%)',
  22: '1001 (30.04%)',
  23: '898 (26.95%)',
  24: '733 (22.00%)',
  25: '0 (0.00%)',
  26: '0 (0.00%)',
  27: '0 (0.00%)',
  28: '0 (0.00%)',
  29: '0 (0.00%)',
  30: '0 (0.00%)',
  31: '1177 (35.32%)',
  32: '0 (0.00%)',
  33: '369 (11.07%)',
  34: '1 (0.03%)',
  35: '150 (4.50%)',
  36: '0 (0.00%)',
  37: '0 (0.00%)',
  38: '675 (20.26%)',
  39: '227 (6.81%)',
  40: '0 (0.00%)',
  41: np.nan,
  42: '0 (0.00%)',
  43: '0 (0.00%)',
  44: '0 (0.00%)',
  45: '0 (0.00%)',
  46: '0.08 [0.05 - 0.14]',
  47: '0.08 [0.05 - 0.14]',
  48: '0.08 [0.05 - 0.13]',
  49: '0.08 [0.05 - 0.13]',
  50: '0.08 [0.05 - 0.14]',
  51: '0.09 [0.05 - 0.14]',
  52: '0.08 [0.05 - 0.13]',
  53: '0.08 [0.05 - 0.13]',
  54: '0.07 [0.04 - 0.13]',
  55: '0.07 [0.05 - 0.13]',
  56: '3.98 [3.63 - 4.28]',
  57: '4.03 [3.73 - 4.33]',
  58: '4.00 [3.68 - 4.29]',
  59: '4.25 [3.91 - 4.50]',
  60: '4.00 [3.64 - 4.29]',
  61: '4.00 [3.62 - 4.30]',
  62: '4.07 [3.79 - 4.33]',
  63: '4.22 [3.92 - 4.52]',
  64: '3.92 [3.58 - 4.22]',
  65: '4.29 [4.00 - 4.58]',
  66: '3.83 [3.50 - 4.17]',
  67: '3.92 [3.55 - 4.25]',
  68: '4.00 [3.67 - 4.32]',
  69: '3.95 [3.63 - 4.24]',
  70: '4.00 [3.61 - 4.32]',
  71: '1.44 [1.14 - 1.89]'},
 'p_value': {0: '0.136',
  1: '<0.001',
  2: '<0.001',
  3: '0.015',
  4: '0.132',
  5: '0.634',
  6: '<0.001',
  7: '<0.001',
  8: '<0.001',
  9: '0.033',
  10: '0.605',
  11: '<0.001',
  12: '<0.001',
  13: np.nan,
  14: '<0.001',
  15: '<0.001',
  16: '0.106',
  17: '<0.001',
  18: '<0.001',
  19: np.nan,
  20: '<0.001',
  21: '<0.001',
  22: '<0.001',
  23: '<0.001',
  24: '<0.001',
  25: '<0.001',
  26: '0.366',
  27: '<0.001',
  28: '<0.001',
  29: '<0.001',
  30: '<0.001',
  31: '<0.001',
  32: '<0.001',
  33: '<0.001',
  34: '<0.001',
  35: '<0.001',
  36: '0.002',
  37: '0.221',
  38: '<0.001',
  39: '<0.001',
  40: '<0.001',
  41: np.nan,
  42: '<0.001',
  43: '0.221',
  44: '<0.001',
  45: '0.081',
  46: '0.315',
  47: '0.084',
  48: '0.170',
  49: '0.002',
  50: '<0.001',
  51: '0.544',
  52: '<0.001',
  53: '0.011',
  54: '0.340',
  55: '0.194',
  56: '0.366',
  57: '0.450',
  58: '0.627',
  59: '0.851',
  60: '0.975',
  61: '0.465',
  62: '0.047',
  63: '0.912',
  64: '0.006',
  65: '<0.001',
  66: '0.220',
  67: '0.923',
  68: '0.038',
  69: '0.610',
  70: '0.259',
  71: '0.021'}}
```

How can I filter the data above such that the result contains the p_value of <= 0.05 or equals to '<0.001'?

The result should be something like this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

convert the p_value as float type first, then filter with `p_value <= 0.05`

```
p_value = df['p_value'].str.strip('<').astype(np.float)
df[p_value <= 0.05]
```

result:

```
                      G1 p_value
1   45.00 [39.00 - 51.00]  <0.001
2            909 (27.28%)  <0.001
3           2029 (60.89%)   0.015
6            577 (17.32%)  <0.001
7               0 (0.00%)  <0.001
8               0 (0.00%)  <0.001
9           2257 (67.74%)   0.033
11              0 (0.00%)  <0.001
12              0 (0.00%)  <0.001
14              0 (0.00%)  <0.001
15          1019 (30.58%)  <0.001
17          1091 (32.74%)  <0.001
18           420 (12.61%)  <0.001
20              0 (0.00%)  <0.001
21          1433 (43.01%)  <0.001
22          1001 (30.04%)  <0.001
23           898 (26.95%)  <0.001
24           733 (22.00%)  <0.001
25              0 (0.00%)  <0.001
27              0 (0.00%)  <0.001
28              0 (0.00%)  <0.001
29              0 (0.00%)  <0.001
30              0 (0.00%)  <0.001
31          1177 (35.32%)  <0.001
32              0 (0.00%)  <0.001
33           369 (11.07%)  <0.001
34              1 (0.03%)  <0.001
35            150 (4.50%)  <0.001
36              0 (0.00%)   0.002
38           675 (20.26%)  <0.001
39            227 (6.81%)  <0.001
40              0 (0.00%)  <0.001
42              0 (0.00%)  <0.001
44              0 (0.00%)  <0.001
49     0.08 [0.05 - 0.13]   0.002
50     0.08 [0.05 - 0.14]  <0.001
52     0.08 [0.05 - 0.13]  <0.001
53     0.08 [0.05 - 0.13]   0.011
62     4.07 [3.79 - 4.33]   0.047
64     3.92 [3.58 - 4.22]   0.006
65     4.29 [4.00 - 4.58]  <0.001
68     4.00 [3.67 - 4.32]   0.038
71     1.44 [1.14 - 1.89]   0.021
```

Comment: very interesting. This is great! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This could do

```
df[df.p_value.str.split('\<').str[-1].astype(float).between(0.001,0.05)]


  

                     G1     p_value
1   45.00 [39.00 - 51.00]  <0.001
2            909 (27.28%)  <0.001
3           2029 (60.89%)   0.015
6            577 (17.32%)  <0.001
7               0 (0.00%)  <0.001
8               0 (0.00%)  <0.001
9           2257 (67.74%)   0.033
11              0 (0.00%)  <0.001
12              0 (0.00%)  <0.001
14              0 (0.00%)  <0.001
15          1019 (30.58%)  <0.001
17          1091 (32.74%)  <0.001
18           420 (12.61%)  <0.001
20              0 (0.00%)  <0.001
21          1433 (43.01%)  <0.001
22          1001 (30.04%)  <0.001
23           898 (26.95%)  <0.001
24           733 (22.00%)  <0.001
25              0 (0.00%)  <0.001
27              0 (0.00%)  <0.001
28              0 (0.00%)  <0.001
29              0 (0.00%)  <0.001
30              0 (0.00%)  <0.001
31          1177 (35.32%)  <0.001
32              0 (0.00%)  <0.001
33           369 (11.07%)  <0.001
34              1 (0.03%)  <0.001
35            150 (4.50%)  <0.001
36              0 (0.00%)   0.002
38           675 (20.26%)  <0.001
39            227 (6.81%)  <0.001
40              0 (0.00%)  <0.001
42              0 (0.00%)  <0.001
44              0 (0.00%)  <0.001
49     0.08 [0.05 - 0.13]   0.002
50     0.08 [0.05 - 0.14]  <0.001
52     0.08 [0.05 - 0.13]  <0.001
53     0.08 [0.05 - 0.13]   0.011
62     4.07 [3.79 - 4.33]   0.047
64     3.92 [3.58 - 4.22]   0.006
65     4.29 [4.00 - 4.58]  <0.001
68     4.00 [3.67 - 4.32]   0.038
71     1.44 [1.14 - 1.89]   0.021
```